# Serialize duplicated namespaces to XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, .net-5

by third party imposition, I need to generate an XML with a duplicated prefix for the same namespace:

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

I am using c# and the xml serializer.

```
 xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, document, _serializerSetup.QualifiedNames);
```

where `_serializerSetup.QualifiedNames` is `XmlSerializerNamespaces(XmlQualifiedName[])`. The serializer always removes the last one, which is duplicated.

I know this doesn't make sense, but is imposed, so....

*edited the QualifiedNames information

Comment: I'm not quite following.  Why do you think you need to have two identical namespace declarations.  Remember, the `xs` and `xsi` are just prefix aliases for the actual namespace.  They have no meaning other than there use within a declaring element

Comment: There's no overload of [`XmlSerializer.Serialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.serialize?view=net-6.0) with a `XmlQualifiedName[]` parameter. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Flydog57, I need to have, because the brilliant minds (being the most ironic I can be) who created the document validator are validating if the document have this two prefixes and some other stuff that is not used in any element.

Comment: @Charles Manger, my bad. is a XmlSerializerNamespaces(XmlQualifiedName[])

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't be possible using the serialiser alone (given there isn't really a use case for doing this). You could serialise to e.g. `XDocument` and modify the root element afterwards before writing to the intended output.

Comment: So you are expected to use both `xs` and `xsi` as namespace prefixes (for the same namespace) in the same document?  That's, uh, _brilliant_ (yeah, you used the right term). Since it's the top level schema, I don't think you could isolate it by element.  Have fun!  Makes me think of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg

Comment: @CharlesMager I used my Thor hammer and did that :( Somehow it now broke the signature... which is added after that.... Thank you all.

Comment: @Flydog57 The video is exactly what I am feeling right now :D

Comment: How about adding a dummy element from this other namespace? Or does the serializer detect the same target and 'normalize' it away? Can you add an element with a different namespace using this different prefix? Or does this validator reject them all?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri, when you have an element, this element belongs to a namespace, regardless the prefix. When un serialize and declare the qualified namespaces array, for each namespace you define a prefix. You can add as many prefixes you want for the same namespace, but the serializer will discard prefixes with the same namespace. The problem here, is the "brilliant" other end which validates if there are namespaces with those specific prefixes on root element, which are not mandatory by xml rules. The solution: String.Replace("pref1:...","pref1... pref2...."). Thor hammer.